# Use Top n on category group in chart

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reportbuilder3.0, top-n

I have a report showing a table showing details, it has about 380 rows.

I want to add a simple bar chart using the same dataset.
In the chart is one value and one group: value = sum(amount) and category group = description order by sum(amount).

This is working fine, but chart is showing about 120 bars, because of 120 distinct descriptions. I only want to display the top n.

Can this be done in reporting services itself or do I need to do this is a query?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself.
There is a filter operator 'Top N' which can be used. It seems the field used in expression doesn't matter.

[image]

However it seems Reporting services first performs the topN en than sort the remaining data. So I had to make a second dataset anyway.